# Under what circumstances will a ChannelPipeline have all of its elements removed?

Tags: netty

I am load testing a Netty application.

The application makes heavy use of [submitting tasks to the `EventExecutor`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutorGroup.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) [reachable from `ChannelHandlerContext#executor()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#executor--), following [Norman Mauer's recommendations](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#24.0).  (The tasks that I submit in this fashion retain a reference to the `ChannelHandlerContext` in effect at submission time.)

After observing strange behavior in the application, I logged the output of `ChannelHandlerContext.pipeline().toMap()` from within one of these tasks as it is executed by the `EventExecutor` on (definitionally) the event loop.

**The pipeline so logged is, surprisingly (to me), empty.**

(I logged the pipeline from within a more conventional `channelRead` method, and needless to say there it is not empty.)

I don't have any logic in my application that removes items from the `ChannelPipeline`.

I am not closing any channels (the client is requesting that connections be kept alive).

I am quite sure that I must be doing something wrong—perhaps I'm not clear on when a `ChannelPipeline` goes out of scope or is otherwise "cleared".  When is a `ChannelPipeline` cleared out by Netty?

Comment: After more debugging today, I also find that `channelHandlerContext.isRemoved()` invoked from within the task that I've submitted to the event loop returns `true`.  This suggests that I cannot simply cache a reference to `ChannelHandlerContext` in a task that is submitted to an event loop.  I thought I could due to the [javadocs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html) which say in part: "You can keep the `ChannelHandlerContext` for later use, such as triggering an event outside the handler methods, even from a different thread."

Comment: My scenario reduces to doing a read, doing some work on a non-event loop thread, and as part of that work submitting write tasks to the event loop. The read activity on the event loop does not write anything; the write occurs only when the non-event loop thread submits a write task to the event loop that retains a `ChannelHandlerContext` reference.  Under load, this `ChannelHandlerContext` "becomes removed", and hence the submitted write task cannot, when run by the event loop, take place.  I thought I was following all the rules, but there must be some more rules that I'm not following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty itself doesn't remove handlers form the Pipeline. `ChannelPipeline` is gathered by GC as regular Java object when it is no longer used (channel holding `ChannelPipeline` is closed).

So either you do that in your code (but you don't) or pipeline is destroyed with the channel.
As you are doing load testing my suggestion is next:

- You create load on your server;
- Test client can't handle enough load and closes some of the connections (pretty common situation during high load tests);
- Netty see that connection is closed and removes the channel (and pipeline with it) and it is gathered with GC;
- As a result you still have the context that is references to the removed channel;

> Under load, this ChannelHandlerContext "becomes removed", and hence
>   the submitted write task cannot, when run by the event loop, take
>   place.

This is expected. Channel could become unavailable at any moment. So if you delegate the task to some thread pool you should check that channel is still active/writable or you can use `ChannelFuture` from the `write()` operation for that.

**Update:**

You have multiple options depending on what you need. You can check the channel is writable before the actual write:

```
if (ctx.channel().isWritable()) {
    //write
}
```

You can check the `ChannelFuture` for the write operation result:

```
ChannelFuture cf = ctx.writeAndFlush();
//cf has a bunch of method + listeners that you can use
```

You can use `ChannelPromise`  as well and override required method.

Netty very flexible and provides many possible flows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  You write: "So if you delegate the task to some thread pool you should check that channel is still active/writable".  I am submitting my write to `ChannelHandlerContext.executor()` (i.e. the event loop).  If I can't write at that point because the channel is not active, what can I do?  And I thought the `ChannelPromise` supplied to the `write()` operation is so I can do something _after_ a write takes place.  In this case no write can take place.

Comment: Thanks again; I really appreciate it. Maybe my biggest problem is: suppose `isWritable` returns `false`.  Then what do I do?  Skip the write entirely?  Isn't that data loss?

Comment: It depends on your needs. You can skip the write. You can store it in some queue or DB, etc.